# Convert Lead into Custom Object called Partner

Tags: custom-object, custom-button

I am new with Apex and I am totally confused with few things. I want to create a button inside Lead object where upon pressing that button I will be able to create Partner Account(custom object) inside salesforce. The function of the button should be exactly the same as the button for Account Convert.

I am creating a custom button called Partner Convert that is located inside the leads next to Convert(button for account). This button should have a trigger that is created in Lead>triggers with the following code up until now.

```
trigger test on Lead (before update) {
 for(Lead lead:System.Trigger.new) {
  if (Lead.IsConverted)
  //convert into custom object Partner
 }
}
```

There i don't know what to write so that I will have most of the objects that I have in the lead to be created inside the Partner.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include specific code that demonstrates your attempts so far, and verbatim error messages if you have encountered any. As written this post is entirely too broad and likely to be closed.

Comment: I am sorry @AdrianLarson i hope this provides more info. If not I will do another detail update.

Comment: Your custom button make little sense now, since you are using Lead trigger on conversion. You could just use standard `Convert` button and tweak your trigger a little to include a list of `Partner` custom object record(s) and insert them outside of `for` loop.

Comment: Yea i am working on a project where there are leads that are coming from partners and other sides. I want have 2 buttons for converting one that converts Accounts and another that converts Partners(which are from custom object - Partner)